# Two levels horizontal dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Consider an ordinary 2 levels dropdown menu:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Main item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav li { position: relative; float: left; }
.nav li a { display: block; }
.nav li ul { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 39px; }
.nav li ul li { float: left; }
```

I'd like the second level items to be displayed horizontally, all in one line. It's not a problem, when we define the width of `ul.menu ul`. But if the number of the second level menu items varies, we can't know the width and so the items are displayed vertically.

Comment: Something that might be causing confusion, is that you haven't actually used the `.nav` class in your html above. Also, how many *main items* do you have and are they displayed vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vishal and Scott Simpson said, `display: inline-block;` is the way to solve the problem. But this method doesn't work in every browser (at least for now). If a parent has `position: relative`, it indirectly determines the maximum width of its children.
So I wrote the following script.

```
$.fn.dropdownNav = function () {

    var dropItem = $(this);

    // your dropdown menu height
    var menuHeight = 38;

    // dropdown menu is not displayed by default, we need to show it
    dropItem.children('ul').show();

    // increase the dropdown menu width, until all items fit in one row
    while ( dropItem.children('ul').height() > menuHeight ) {
        dropItem.children('ul').css({ width: '+=1' });
    }

    // it is done, let's hide the dropdown menu
    dropItem.children('ul').hide();

    // and bind hover events
    dropItem.hover (
        function () { $(this).children('ul').show(); },
        function () { $(this).children('ul').hide(); }
    );
};

// function call
$('.nav > li').each(function () { $(this).dropdownNav(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

1) First give id to your elements.

2) Use display: inline in your second li.

3) Then you give it a common width place a div span inside each li example and give them all the same  width.

```
<li><div id='1'>ur data ,</div></li>
```

Also place your text  in the center

```
text-align: center;
```

Hope this helps.

The below code is working for me in ff and chrome.
css:

```
.nav li { position: relative; float: left; }
.nav li a { display: block; }
.nav li ul { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 39px; }
.nav li ul li { float: left; }

ul.menu ul li {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear for me. Could you provide more detailed code, please?

Comment: I wrote, that it didn't work in browsers, only in jsFiddle. You can try it by yourself.

Comment: The only exception - webkit browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using display: inline-block on the child list items: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bd3SX/

Comment: Unfortunately, your example works in jsFiddle, but not in browsers.